# Openlayers 3 with new ol.Vector returns [Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]

Tags: javascript, php, openlayers-3

I have a search form to call a Solr index, filled with geolocations:

```js
jQuery('.form-submit', element).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    search();
});

function search() {
    useBBOX = false;

    combinedExtent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
    data.map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer, index, array) {
        if (layer.getSource() instanceof ol.source.Vector) {
            var source = layer.getSource().getSource();
            var url = data.opt.urls[source.get('machineName')];
            var newSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                loader: getLoader(data, url),
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
                reloadOnZoomChange: true,
                reloadOnExtentChange: true
            });

            newSource.set('machineName', source.get('machineName'));
            var newCluster = new ol.source.Cluster({
                source: newSource,
                distance: 200 
            });
            layer.setSource(newCluster);
        }
    });
}

function getLoader(data, url) {
    return function (extent, resolution, projection) {
         var bbox = ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, data.map.getView().getProjection(), 'EPSG:4326');

        var params = {};
        if (data.opt.paramForwarding) {
            var get_params = location.search.substring(location.search.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            jQuery.each(get_params, function (i, val) {
                if (val.length) {
                    var param = val.split('=');
                  
                    params[decodeURIComponent(param[0])] = (param[1] !== undefined) ? decodeURIComponent(param[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : '';
                }
            })
        }

        if (useBBOX == true) {
            params.bbox = bbox.join(',');
            params.zoom = data.map.getView().getZoom();
        }
        var searchQuery = jQuery('#input-search-address').val();

        if (searchQuery != 'undefined' && searchQuery != null) {
            url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); 
            url = url + searchQuery;
        }
        jQuery(document).trigger('openlayers.bbox_pre_loading', [{
            'url': url,
            'params': params,
            'data': data
        }]);

        var that = this;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: params,
            success: function (responsdata) {
              
                var features = that.getFeaturesInExtent(extent);
                jQuery(features).each(function (i, f) {
                    that.removeFeature(f);
                });
                var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                var features = format.readFeatures(responsdata, {featureProjection: projection});
                that.addFeatures(features);
                that._loadingFeatures = false;

                if (!ol.extent.isEmpty(that.getExtent())) {
                    combinedExtent = ol.extent.extend(combinedExtent, that.getExtent());
           
                    if (useBBOX == false) {
                        useBBOX = true; 
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Basically, it fetches 3 layers, each containing a number of markers. I'ld like to autozoom the map based on those markers. Therefore I'm looking for the `extent`. The `combinedExtent` does contain all correct extents...

[image]

... but when I add `data.map.getView().fit(combinedExtent, data.map.getSize())` INSIDE the `getLoader` function, it's not working. I looks like only 1 extent get plotted on the map.

Whenever I try to log the `combinedExtent` in the `search()` function, I get a weird error...

[image]

Google told me I had to *wait* until the `getState()` of `newSource` was `ready`, but that didn't work out... 
So, I'm looking for a solution. My guess would be the use of the ajax return in `getLoader`...

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, so I have a function to listen until the source is ready and finished loading before giving a count of features (otherwise it would update the log with every iteration).  Just change my source name (any variable with "parcelquery in it) with yours and hopefully it will at least put you in the right direction.

```js
var listenerKey = wfsSource_parcelquery.on('change', function(e) {
    if (wfsSource_parcelquery.getState() == 'ready') {  //says source is done loading
        var featureCount = wfsSource_parcelquery.getFeatures().length; //getting number of features resulting from query
        ol.Observable.unByKey(listenerKey);
        // use vectorSource.unByKey(listenerKey) instead
        // if you do use the "master" branch of ol3
    }
    alert("Your query returned "+ featureCount + " results."); 
    var extent = lyr_parcelquery.getSource().getExtent();      
    console.log(extent);             
    map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());  
});
```